# Glassfish 3.1b41 - JDO83008: CMP Compilation failed: class file not found

Tags: java, deployment, glassfish, glassfish-3

we have an "old" JavaEE Application, which we want to port from the old Sun Application Server 9.1 to the current Glassfish 3.1. We updated the deployment descriptor xml files (renamed them, updated DocType, validated against DTD, nothing else). But when we try to the deploy into the GF3.1 we get this error:

```
JDO83008: CMP Compilation failed: 
C:\workspace\glassfish31eclipsedefaultdomain\generated\ejb\archivetool-app-1.9.5\archivetool-ejb-1.9.5_jar\de\ems\archivetool\ejb\metadata\cd\eb\CdBean_821611534_ConcreteImpl.java:10: 
cannot access de.ems.archivetool.ejb.framework.AbstractCMPBean
class file for de.ems.archivetool.ejb.framework.AbstractCMPBean not found

C:\workspace\glassfish31eclipsedefaultdomain\generated\ejb\archivetool-app-1.9.5\archivetool-ejb-1.9.5_jar\de\ems\archivetool\ejb\productdata\product\eb\ProductionLibraryBean40992531_ConcreteImpl.java:416: 
cannot find symbol

symbol  : class EBSBusinessException
location: package de.ems.archivetool.ejb.framework

WARNUNG: JDO83004: CMP Compilation failed. See log for details.
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer prepare method
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer prepare method
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception while preparing the app
SCHWERWIEGEND: JDO83004: CMP Compilation failed. See log for details.
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: JDO83004: CMP Compilation failed. See log for details.
```

But we can still deploy in the old SUN App Server.

The application consists of 4 modules and a build module. Generally, the .ear file, consisting of the two EJB modules, one WAR module and one JAR module, is build with Maven without problems (UnitTest succeed etc).
([pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/KipvizXM) and the resulting [application.xml](http://pastebin.com/16f0BbWX))

So, everything builds fine, but when we try to deploy the application to GF3.1 we get the "class file not found" error. The classes which are not found are within the JAR module and contain base classes for the EJB modules.

Does anyone has a starting point?

Regards,
Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after hours of googeling, I finally found the exact answer to this problem [here](http://hanscappelle.blogspot.de/2010/07/ear-deployment-on-glassfish-3-vs.html).
The important part is:

> The Java EE 6 specification imposes strict rules about which JAR files
>   are visible from an enterprise archive (EAR) file. Refer to section
>   EE.8.3.3; specifically, application client modules should not have
>   access to any EJB JAR file unless the application client JAR file's
>   manifest Class-Path refers to the EJB JAR file(s) explicitly.
>
> This is a change from GlassFish Server v2, in which application
>   clients automatically had access to all EJB JAR files in the EAR file
>   and all JAR files at the top level of the EAR file. To comply with the
>   stricter specification language, GlassFish Server 3.0.1 cannot
>   automatically provide application clients with access to these JAR
>   files.

What you have to do is, let maven put the jar (and other dependencies) into a library folder in the ear container. You do this by adding this to your ear pom.xml:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>

      //here starts the important part
      <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
      //end of important part

   <modules>
     <jarModule>
       <groupId>gID</groupId>
       <artifactId>aID</artifactId>
     </jarModule>

     //etc some more ebjs, war, ...
   </modules>
```

This will put the jar module into a folder lib, and all depending ejbs will get the Class-Path entry in their MANIFEST.MF.

Hope that helps some of you with the same problem.